# Java multithreading - try to obtain lock until after some time has passed?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

I was not able to find a solution for my question after browsing for a bit.

I have a class `box.java` with its own lock that contains a method `methodA` and a `methodB`.

I have multiple threads that try to access these box objects. What I want is for the thread to try executing `methodA`, and after a certain amount of time, if it cannot obtain the lock on the box, then execute `methodB`.

Is there a way to do this in Java?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have one thread that stays in a mutex for so long that other threads waiting to get in have to time out, then you are probably doing something wrong.  "Wrong" in the sense that, That's not what mutexes are _for_, and other programmers may get confused when they try to read your code.  It's very likely that there is some other synchronization object (blocking queue maybe?  hard to say without knowing more about your application) that is more appropriate.  Or, if not, you probably could craft your own using condition variables.

Answer (score 5):

the `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock` interface has a `tryLock(long, TimeUnit)` method that does just that.

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html

as far as i know this is not possible with the built in monitor locks (the ones used by the `synchronized` keyword).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a Notifier class. I had done something like that before what I quoted , I hope you can figure out what you need .

```
    public class WaitNotifyTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Message msg = new Message("process it");
            Waiter waiter = new Waiter(msg);
            new Thread(waiter,"waiter 1 ").start();

            Waiter waiter1 = new Waiter(msg);
            new Thread(waiter1, "waiter 2 ").start();

            Notifier notifier = new Notifier(msg);
            new Thread(notifier, "notifier").start();
            System.out.println("All the threads are started");
        }

    }

    class Message {
        private String msg;

        public Message(String str){
            this.msg=str;
        }

        public String getMsg() {
            return msg;
        }

        public void setMsg(String str) {
            this.msg=str;
        }

    }


    class Notifier implements Runnable {

        private Message msg;

        public Notifier(Message msg) {
            this.msg = msg;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            System.out.println(name+" started");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                synchronized (msg) {
                    msg.setMsg(name+" Notify Tread 1");
                    msg.notify();

                    msg.setMsg(name+" Notify Tread 2");
                    msg.notify();

                    msg.setMsg(name+" Notify Tread 3");
                    msg.notify();
    //                 msg.notifyAll();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }



    class Waiter implements Runnable{

        private Message msg;

        public Waiter(Message m){
            this.msg=m;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            synchronized (msg) {
                try{
                    System.out.println(name+" waiting to get notified at time:"+System.currentTimeMillis());
                    msg.wait();
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(name+" waiter thread got notified at time:"+System.currentTimeMillis());
                //process the message now
                System.out.println(name+" processed: "+msg.getMsg());
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do so.

1. You can use `synchronized methods` in java to obtain lock and use
   `thread.wait()` method in that `synchronized method`.
2. You can use `semaphore` in java
3. Use of `blocking queues`

You can get tutorial of all of above [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/semaphores.html).